# How to change the whole object and artboard in Sketch once it is created?

Tags: sketch-app, resize, artboard

I created an artboard in Sketch with size 512x512 and created all the objects on it. Later I found that the size required to be used in my app is 84x84, so I have to change the size of the objects to fit the required size.

However, when I select the artboard and resize it to 84x84, and then select all the objects to 84x84, then it is no longer put on the proper related location. In other words all the objects got the wrong aspect ratio (if I understand it correctly).

So how can I change the size to the different size once I created and ended all the design work in the project? I use Sketch 3.7.

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the artboard as well as all the layers on it, while keeping the relative distance of each object, first select the artboard and then `Edit` | `Scale` (or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) to resize it whatever you want.

You can change the size either by specifying the pixel size or scale percentage and Sketch automatically computes the other variable.

[image]

The source: https://www.reddit.com/r/sketchapp/comments/3arj1m/question_how_to_resize_artboards/